# Gstreamer amplify specific frequencies

Tags: python, gstreamer, audio-processing, python-gstreamer

I need to gain volume to specific frequency (or range of frequencies). Closest I get is using `audiochebband` with `band-reject`. Sample pipeline would be:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc wave=9 samplesperbuffer=44100 num-buffers=30 volume=0.05 ! \
audio/x-raw,channels=2 ! audioconvert ! \
audiochebband lower-frequency=980 upper-frequency=1000 mode="band-reject" type=1 ripple=60 ! \
vorbisenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=amp.ogg
```

It gives me some 'some' results. After looking at the plot spectrum, there is huge cut-off after initial amplify of the given frequencies.

[image: Bad plot spectrum]

I need result like if you use , let say, equilizer inside audacidy, select points between two frequencies and move points up, like this.

[image: Good plot spectrum]

Edit:
As an illustration of the requirements I have, here is the simple python script that reads wav file, and amplify range of frequencies.

```py
from __future__ import print_function, division
import wave
import numpy as np
import time

start_time = time.time()
wr = wave.open('input-file.wav', 'r')
par = list(wr.getparams()) # Get the parameters from the input.
# This file is stereo, 2 bytes/sample, 44.1 kHz.
par[3] = 0 # The number of samples will be set by writeframes.

# Open the output file
ww = wave.open('output-file.wav', 'w')
ww.setparams(tuple(par)) # Use the same parameters as the input file.

lowcut = 980 # Select frequencies from.
highcut = 1000 # Select frequencies to.

sz = wr.getframerate() # Read and process 1 second at a time.
c = int(wr.getnframes()/sz) # whole file
for num in range(c):
    print('Processing {}/{} s'.format(num+1, c))
    da = np.frombuffer(wr.readframes(sz), dtype=np.int16)
    left, right = da[0::2], da[1::2] # left and right channel
    lf, rf = np.fft.rfft(left), np.fft.rfft(right)
    lf[lowcut:highcut] *= 2
    rf[lowcut:highcut] *= 2
    nl, nr = np.fft.irfft(lf), np.fft.irfft(rf)
    ns = np.column_stack((nl,nr)).ravel().astype(np.int16)
    ww.writeframes(ns.tostring())
# Close the files.
wr.close()
ww.close()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Generating with noise, and use it as input file with script, there is a perfect gain in selected rage.

Comment: Are you looking to amplify a narrow range of frequencies? What frequency range exactly?

Comment: I think that for type1 the ripple is on the pass band. 60 dB ripple in the pass band may be what causes the odd output. Reduce the ripple and/or increase the width of the band. Increasing samplerate can sometimes also help

Comment: Yes. It must be user configurable. It can range from one to n range. Using this method for one or two frequencies, the result is ok because by the docs "some ferquencies may be amplified", but with wider range it amplifies only couple of first and last. I know about equilizer-nbands (or 3,10...) but I can't fine tune which to amplify because all band range is amplified that way.

Comment: Of course, changing to band-pass creates nice pointy arrow in graph but all other frequencies outside of given range is affected and non-existing. Any amount of ripple above 5 creates same gap in the original pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes. It must be user configurable. It can range from one to n range.
> Using this method for one or two frequencies, the result is ok because
> by the docs "some ferquencies may be amplified", but with wider range
> it amplifies only couple of first and last. I know about
> equilizer-nbands (or 3,10...) but I can't fine tune which to amplify
> because all band range is amplified that way.

The following is just a suggestion (I can't test as I'm not set up), but as you are successful with one or two frequencies, perhaps you use multiple invocations to amplify subsets of your intending frequencies into different outputs / streams, and then mix the output into a single stream / file.

For example, say you need to amplify 980-2000. Lets start with what you say works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 audiotestsrc wave=9 samplesperbuffer=44100 num-buffers=30 volume=0.05 ! \
audio/x-raw,channels=2 ! audioconvert ! \
audiochebband lower-frequency=980 upper-frequency=1000 mode="band-reject" type=1 ripple=60 ! \
vorbisenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=amp.ogg
```

In the above example you are specifying 980-1000.

You can have separate invocations for:

```
1000-1020
1020-1040
....
1980-2000
```

All outputting to different files.

Then you can use something like the following to mix several streams into one by adding the data:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/audiomixer/audiomixer.html?gi-language=c

or:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/adder/index.html?gi-language=c

Comment: this may work, only if I separate to range of 1 or 2 frequencies at a time. 20 (as in my example) gives me unexpected results. Lets's consider timings, I need to create massive pipeline in order to achieve this, and it will need good amount of time to achieve this but my project produces about 2 hours long sound. I need a solution that is based on fft, similar to Audacity Filter Curve EQ.

Comment: @Aleksandar if spending a little funds aren’t an issue, just run a script on AWS - even if it’s a large frequency range you can run multiple invocations of the script in parallel. Otherwise, audacity is open source, so you can get some ideas there.